# How do I prevent people from adding extra reactions? Discord JS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a bot and I want to limit people to four reactions on the embed. So how would I limit them to just any four reactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Client#messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event, which is fired whenever a reaction is added to a message.

You can check if the message has more than 4 reactions and remove the reaction if needed.

---

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (MessageReaction, User) => {
    if (MessageReaction.message.reactions.cache.size > 4) MessageReaction.remove();
});
```

Comment: Whenever you are adding a reaction, you can check if the message has more than 4 reactions. Each message object has `reactions.cache.size`.